# ReactJS checkbox default value

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I'm having a problem setting a checkbox to checked right on load to always be selected by the user using ReactJS. I'm fairly new to react and i'm struggling a lot with this kind of things for now.

My code is like this

```
import DbCheckbox2 from 'modules/Checkbox-Checked'

const GenerateTemplateComponent = ({
  handleSubmit,
  handleCancel,
  classes
}) => {
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      validate={validate}
      render={({ handleSubmit, invalid, pristine, form: { change } }) => (
        <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <PanelBody>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
                <Field
                  name='name'
                  component={DbInputField}
                  required
                  label={<FormattedMessage id='offre-name' />}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs={6} md={6}>
                  <Field
                    //className={classes.inputCheckbox}
                    name='section'
                    component={DbCheckbox2}
                    type='checkbox'
                    color='primary'
                    label={<FormattedMessage id='offre-section' />}  
                  />
                </Grid>
```

And on the *Checkbox-Checked* file is like this

```
import React from 'react'

import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl'
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel'
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox'

const DbCheckbox2 = ({
  label,
  className,
  checked=true,
  value=true,
}) => (
  <FormControl className={className} component="fieldset">
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={checked}
          value={value}
        />
      }
      label={label}
    />
  </FormControl>
)

export default DbCheckbox2
```

I tried to add **value="true"** on the field properties, and i get a value="true" on the html, but its really get me the results i desire when i click again on the checkbox, like the first time its doesn't recognize. Maybe he awaiting a onclick event or something, but i dont get it at all. Any help?

Comment: where in the app do you set the initial state, I think you'll just have to set `checked: true` in the state and pass down as props to `DbCheckbox2`

Comment: thats almost it, solved with initial value, gonna answer the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with initialValues on the form, making the checkboxs values true right on load, like that:

```
<Form
  initialValues={{
    section: true,
    menus: true
  }}
```

continues from that, the name of the field is used to pass the **true** value.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the standard way of setting the initial values. Did you followed a guild that encourages doing so?

Comment: Im not sure either, but i'm working on a already going project. They use initialValues proprety for another forms, i just getting along hahah. But to me, a beginner programmer, its looks like a way to use uncontrolled component from the react docs, but i really not sure.

Comment: I suspect that is the correct way. A more proper way is either pass them as props and validate the prop types or use componentDidMount to set the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

This shows you how to handle checked state a in checkbox:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checkbox1: true };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange(e) {
      const element = e.target;
      this.setState({
          [element.name]: element.checked
      });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
        <input
         type="checkbox"
          name='checkbox1'
          checked={this.state.checkbox1}
          onChange={ this.handleChange }/>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: This work to but not exactly as i wanted to do. My code was checking the boxes but not setting the value to true(dont know why). Solved the question bellow. Thanks for the help